# why is the open() syscall supported on some Linux systems and not others?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm64, archlinux-arm

I am inlining syscalls. Yes, I understand this is problematic but I have a good reason. I've tracked down my bug considerably and I'm just asking why has *__NR_open* disappeared on this arm64 Arch Linux system?

> 5.0.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP Sun Mar 10 15:08:34 MDT 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Again, my code is inlining syscalls. This inlining approach works on another *X86_64* system and indeed inlining *mmap()* works on this system. However, inlining *open()* on this arm64 Arch Linux failed with *EFAULT*.

Tracking down my bug, first, *__NR_open* is NOT even defined in this build environment. Second, regular *open()* calls *open64()* which executes an *svc* instruction with x8 set to #56, *__NR_openat*. Third, *__NR_open* is normally defined as 5 and that number has been repurposed to *__NR_setxattr*. This explains the *EFAULT*.

Basically, *open()* gets converted into *openat()* in a user library on this system and the *__NR_open* syscall has completely disappeared, taken over by a new syscall. What I don't understand is that *__NR_open* is defined in the [canonical source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm64/include/asm/unistd32.h) for arm64 but just not on this Arch Linux arm64 system.

My bug fix is simple: inline *openat()* instead. But my question is why was this deleted and why is this not considered broken from a Linux POV? I'm thinking of Linus saying *WE DO NOT BREAK USERSPACE!* and I'm *not* thinking about this from a POSIX POV. Indeed *The Linux Programming Interface* doesn't cover this deletion at least not explicitly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The file you are looking at, `arch/arm64/include/asm/unistd32.h`, is the system call definitions for the arm32 compat mode.

The system call definitions for native aarch64 are from the generic system call table [include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h), which you can see does not define `__NR_open`.  The system call was not deleted - it *never* existed on aarch64.

The reason that `__NR_open` is not defined in the generic table is that the `openat(2)` system call was introduced later and is a strict superset of the `_NR_open` functionality, so there is no point in *new* architecture ports (created after `openat(2)` was introduced) supplying that system call - it is redundant.  The POSIX `open()` function is supplied by the userspace C library, calling into the `openat(2)` system call.

Old architecture ports that existed prior to `openat(2)` - like x86, and arm32 - must continue to include `open(2)`, because old programs/library binaries certainly exist for those architectures that call the `open(2)` system call.  This concern does not apply to a new architecture port - the "breaking userspace" guarantee is that if it worked yesterday it will work today, but it does not say that if it worked on an existing architecture it can be recompiled and work on some new architecture.